# VS Code Extensions: Find and replace a string in workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I googled a lot and did not find any working way to search inside a specific file inside the `vscode.workspace` and replace the found terms.

So basicly **I want to search the `vscode.workspace` for a file named app.component.ts, and check if the file contains a // my-marker. If so this marker should be replaced by some other string.**

Does anybody know if this is possible? And if so, how?
This is my approach:

```
function createAppEnvironment(name: string)
{
  if(name != undefined)
  {
    // replace all blanks ' ' with dashes '-'
    name = name.replace(/\w/g, '-');

    vscode.workspace.findFiles('app/app.component.ts', '', 1).then(
        // all good
        (result: vscode.Uri[]) => {
            vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(result[0]);
            vscode.commands.executeCommand('edit.findAndReplace');
        },
        // rejected
        (reason: any) => {
            // output error
            vscode.window.showErrorMessage(reason);
        });

    // Display a message box to the user
    // vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Successfully created a new App!');
}
else
{
    vscode.window.showWarningMessage("Nothing was created, due to the fact that you haven't entered a name.");
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't done this myself, so I'm kinda winging it here...

Instead of opening find/replace:

1. Use TextDocument.getText() to get the text.
2. Use a regular expression to find your marker.
3. Use TextDocument.positionAt() to get a Position for building a Range in the document that you need to edit.
4. Create a WorkspaceEdit object that represents your change, using WorkspaceEdit.replace() to indicate the actual edit.
5. Use Workspace.applyEdit() to apply the edit.

Comment: Hi thank you for yor quick answer! This sounds good but how could I target the right document from the workspace? (step "0")

Comment: @jlang Workspace.findFiles() should work as you have it (though you probably don't need the "app/" part).

Comment: @jlang A better solution is to use `vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document` to get the currently active document.